# What is the most efficient way to handle points / small vectors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, performance

Currently I'm creating an web based (= JavaScript) application thata is using a lot of "points" (= small, fixed size vectors). There are basically two obvious ways of representing them:

```
var pointA = [ xValue, yValue ];
```

and

```
var pointB = { x: xValue, y: yValue };
```

So translating my point a bit would look like:

```
var pointAtrans = [ pointA[0] + 3, pointA[1] + 4 ];
var pointBtrans = { x: pointB.x + 3, pointB.y + 4 };
```

Both are easy to handle from a programmer point of view (the object variant is a bit more readable, especially as I'm mostly dealing with 2D data, seldom with 3D and hardly with 4D - but never more. It'll allways fit into x,y,z and w)

But my question is now:
What is the most efficient way from the language perspective - theoretically and in real implementations?
What are the memory requirements?
What are the setup costs of an array vs. an object?
...

My target browsers are FireFox and the Webkit based ones (Chromium, Safari), but it wouldn't hurt to have a great (= fast) experience under IE and Opera as well...

Comment: My feeling says that objects consume less memory: An object is the basic data structure in JS. Arrays are build on top of objects and provide additional methods. But the difference is probably negligible.

Comment: Additional methods are stored on `Array.prototype`. No array holds them directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers and the input. Very interesting were the results of the test written by galamalazs: http://jsperf.com/object-vs-array/2

Taking all aspects together we'll get:

- Arrays should be indexed by number and not by string (arr[0] vs. arr['0'])
- Performance between the Object and the Array form differs mostly by implementation not by type.
- There is no winner, it changes from implementation to implementation
- Future implementations of the browsers known today might also change who's winning - in either way
- On Chromium the Arrays will use half the memory of the Object - but we are talking about 40 MB and 80 MB for one million instances - that is 40 to 80 bytes each.
- The memory consumption of other JavaScript implementations is not known - but it'll most probably also differ as much as the performance.

So in the end both options are sensible and only the code readability will make the decision!

If it's mostly for storing data with trivial work (like in my current project) the Object way is the way to go. An `mouse.x` and `mouse.y` trivially shows the developer intend.

In mostly mathematically oriented applications with vector maths like coordinate transformations (especially going to 3D) the best way would be the Array case as things like matrix multiplications would look more native to the developer and show his intent.

Answer (score 6):

Arrays are faster to create, but if you consider access time it's the other way around. Also note, that **constructor form** is fast to create and access. It has the best of both words in modern implementations  `new Vector(x, y)` - **[[Test](http://jsperf.com/object-vs-array/3)]** 
[image]

**Browsers tested:** *Chrome 10, Firefox 3.6, Firefox Beta 4.0b9, IE 9 Preview 7, Opera 11*

Comment: Array and object access makes nearly no difference in Chrome 8. But array creation is much faster.

Comment: hmm... I would guess the slower access for array values is the coercion from a number to a string.  Remember that arrays *are* objects, so array indexes are actually still just properties on an object. `arr[0]` and `arr["0"]` are functionally the same, but the former should be *slightly* slower in theory.

Comment: @Felix - Yes but he said he wants the best for **FF** and Chrome. And there is 20% difference in FF4.0b9 for me (and even greater for 3.6).

Comment: As I've written on the answer above, I'm fearing to base my decision only on benchmark results.
So the `arr[0]` vs. `arr['0']` might be totally irrelevant when a JIT based implementation can optimize that const away.

Comment: @Chris - You have the option to optimize for implementations do not even exist. That's your call. :) Just decide if you want fast user experience for people living today or maybe 10 years from now. :)

Comment: Now I've extended the test by the string case: http://jsperf.com/object-vs-array/2

It's easy to see, that there's no correct answer by the current implementations of JavaScript.

What we can say is that only an "old" FF has (slightly) faster access times by using strings - the other browsers suffer significantly.  

Apart from that it's undecided...

Does someone know about the memory consumption? (Is there even a way to measure it, like the C sizeof()?)

Comment: @Chris - I don't want to sound too offensive but you seem to miss common sense in this case. :) *"It's easy to see, that there's no correct answer"* - What I see is not to use strings, and then it's fast everywhere. Think about it...

Comment: @galambalazs: you are right that this has reached the point where we can stop and say that the implementation side doesn't matter - even if it would give us an answer, that it doesn't - and only the developer side matters.

The only missing "answer" left was the memory consumption. Using the Chromium profiler and storing a million of 2D arrays and vectors I see a slight difference: the arrays need 80 MB, the objects 38 MB.

Comment: @Chris: I've just realized, it actually makes sense that `arr['0']` would be slower - because there's also a `ToString(ToUint32('0')) === '0'` performed due to the special nature of array objects.  Perhaps Firefox already has optimizations in place to avoid this kind of redundancy.

Comment: @Andy: The cost of finding out its an indexed property is done are parse-time, so it has no run-time cost (which is all jsperf tests). I'm suspicious however that the access test is bias towards objects by the cost of setting the properties and not the access itself.

Comment: @Andy: Of course, it's obvious that Firefox 3.6 doesn't do this at parse-time, but other implementations do.

Comment: @gsnedders: that seems unlikely - an implementation cannot know the value of a variable at parse time and so cannot know the result of `ToString(ToUint32(var))`.

Comment: @Andy: You can't do it in the case that it's a variable, but arr['0'] is a constant, known at parse-time, so ToString(ToUint32('0')) can be determined at parse-time.

Comment: @gsnedders: oh, I see what you mean.  I wrote it like that to simplify what I was saying, but I was intending it to apply more generally to any value or variable unknown at parse time.

Answer (score 2):

My hunch is that Arrays will give you better performance.(!)

That said, the code is already significantly less readable in your Array example than in your Object example.  The gains are likely slight, so I suggest you do some basic benchmarking and back-of-the-napkin math to put a real number on the tradeoff.

For starters, you could

- Start a timer
- Construct 1 thousand random [X,Y] `Arrays`
- Access their fields 1 million times.
- Repeat with `Objects` and compare.

(!) - A good example of why benchmarking is so useful: Arrays are indeed better for creation, but Objects are better for access, which could be very important (depending on your needs). galambalazs has written a great test for this case: http://jsperf.com/object-vs-array

Comment: You are right that only a benchmark will give "the answer" - but JavaScript currently has a huge momentum in getting faster and even faster implementations I fear that the design decision based on current benchmarks will soon be obsolete...

Comment: You are correct. In fact, unless I'm implementing something with special performance needs (or the magnitude of the tradeoff forces my hand), I *always* favor saving developer time vs. saving machine time, particularly on prototypes.  As any any software development, Encapsulate Well and Don't Repeat Yourself, so refactoring can happen later without much pain.

Comment: With Google V8, I think the class version will be as fast as compiled C++ code.